# Why did Visual Studio 2008 stop reporting memory leaks?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, memory, detection, memory-leaks

Our office uses Visual Studio 2008 for development. It has built-in memory leak detection and has always seemed to work properly. Very recently, I checked some code in that had a fair bit of allocation using "new", and I was surprised that I didn't have any memory leaks reported.

When my coworker ran the code, his version of Visual Studio found lots of them. I don't know what happened. Somehow, either the leak detection or the reporting of it has gotten turned off in my copy of VS. We use SourceSafe to manage the code base, so we're using identical code.

I've had no luck searching for a solution. All I can find is stuff like this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). I know there are third party leak detection solutions, but I'd really like to understand how this got disabled in Visual Studio. If anyone knows, please share.

Comment: oh, no! SourceSafe? You have larger issues in your code base than this...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's still there. You need to follow the [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Presumably you missed on of these steps somehow. Perhaps you were running a RELEASE build by mistake. Kind of hard to tell from here.